# try block does not catch TcpClient connect exception

Tags: vb.net, exception, try-catch, tcpclient

I'm opening a TcpClient connection in VB.Net and I have put that part of the code in a try/catch block. But still the compiled program crashed with an unhandled exception when the IP-Address wasn't available.

```
Try
    ' Open connection 
    Dim client As System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient = New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient
    client.Connect(Printer.IpAddress, Printer.Port)
    ' Write ZPL String to connection 
    Dim writer As System.IO.StreamWriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter(client.GetStream(), System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252))
    writer.Write(EtikettText)
    writer.Flush()
    ' Close Connection 
    writer.Close()
    client.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly Or MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Druckerfehler")
    lastex = ex
    Return False
End Try
```

I thought this kind of general try/catch would catch all exceptions. However the program crashed with this call stack:

Error: No connection could be established because the target computer refused the connection 192.168.1.158:9100

Stack trace:

```
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect(IPEndPoint remoteEP)
at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect(IPAddress address, Int32 port)
at Cocos.ChargenEtikett.Print()
```

Comment: try catch didn't catch the error maybe because the error is not with your program but with the other side. The printer could have rejected the access of your program.

Comment: What is this method? Is it `Print`? Also, you say "the compiled program". Does the same thing happen when you press F5 in Visual Studio? Because the code you listed should catch the exception. If the exception isn't caught, then "the compiled program" is not the same as the code you posted.

Comment: MAC, even if the other side rejects access, I think I still should be able to catch it and give a decent error message. The program crashing is rather harsh I think.

Comment: John Saunders, yes this method is print. The device on the other side is a specialty label printer. I say compiled program because this happened in the exe installed at my client. However, I am 100% certain this is the same code.